# Como aplicar una función lambda en una columna en función de valores NaT

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

tengo una columna con fechas, y quiero aplicar una función lambda condicional, que le de el valor uno a la columna 'Type' en caso de que los valores sean NaT Estoy teniendo muchos problemas para detectar estos NaT.

Con unique obtengo los valores vacíos, y me dice que son NaT

```
df['fechaActivacion'].unique()
```

El resultado es el siguiente:

array([                          'NaT', '2022-08-02T15:27:28.000000000',
'2022-07-09T21:10:03.000000000', ...,
'2022-06-27T17:17:50.000000000', '2022-08-10T21:56:10.000000000',
'2022-08-23T17:53:08.000000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')

He intentado lo siguiente:

```
df['type'] = df['fechaActivacion'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x == pd.NaT else 0)
```

No me salta ningún error, pero todos los valores se generan como 0, cuando hay valores NaT y deberían haberse generado 1´s también.

Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según [la documentación](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/missing_data.html#propagation-in-arithmetic-and-comparison-operations), se debe usar la función `isna`, en lugar de una comparación normal, para comprobar si un valor es *faltante*.

```python
df['type'] = df['fechaActivacion'].apply(lambda x: 1 if pd.isna(x) else 0)
```

O mejor aun:

```python
df['type'] = df['fechaActivacion'].apply(lambda x: int(pd.isna(x)))
```

Comment: gracias por la respuesta! Me ha servido, un saludo

Comment: O mejor: `df['fechaActivacion'].isna().astype(int)`